# Convert NoSQL data to SQL data Python

Tags: python, dataframe, nosql, relational

I try to use Python access Redshift database, and use the following code to see a few records. (credential is not shown, but it works) And it's at NoSQL format. How can I change it to relational data structure format or a dataframe? Thanks!

```
import psycopg2
con=psycopg2.connect(...)

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM public.sku_lu limit 2;")
cur.fetchall()
```

Output:

[('sku_1', 'true'),
('sku_2', 'false')]

The output is NoSQL format without a column name. How may I change it to a relational data structure format or a dataframe like below?

| Sku | Base |
| --- | --- |
| sku_1 | true |
| sku_2 | false |

Comment: That isn't "NOSQL" format that is just data types that Python actually has built in. I'm pretty sure you can turn it into a pandas dataframe with one line of code though.

Comment: @unltd_J yes thanks actually yes it's one line for code adding columns from array to a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np_array = np.array(cur.fetchall())
data = pd.DataFrame(np_array, columns=['Sku', 'base'])
```

Solve with above by adding column names